# Create a connected user with payouts_enabled in test mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments, ruby-on-rails-6

Suppose we wish to perform a simple manual test of stripe connect in an app:

1. Create a regular user
2. Create a connected user
3. regular user pays connected user

The problem is, unless `payouts_enabled` is true in step 2, then we'll always get an error when the regular user tries to pay the connected user.

Also, the way to get `details_submitted` is true, is by going through the browser and entering dummy info, but the problem is the test suite doesn't simply allow test info to pass - you have to enter things like social security number, street address etc manually, and it inevitably doesn't pass Stripe's standards, so `details_submitted` can be true, but `payouts_enabled` inevitably remains false

#### Question

I need a way to create a connected user with `payouts_enabled` in test mode. How can I do this?

#### Note

I hope there may be two possibilities to achieve this:

1. programatically using some ruby code in the Stripe gem to generate a connected user with `payouts_enabled == true`
2. through the browser (i.e. by knowing the values for address, social security number, phone number that will pass Stripe's checks and ensure `payouts_enabled == true`

Comment: According to the docs https://stripe.com/docs/connect/testing#payouts, "Test mode Standard accounts always have payouts enabled, as long as valid external bank information and other relevant conditions are met, and never requires real identity verification." So it seems the connected user needs legit bank info but nothing else.

Comment: Although you have to complete the identity verification steps, you can do it via the API with Custom connect accounts. Usually it's recommended to set up such an account in test mode and then reuse it for CI purposes: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/testing-verification

Comment: @dbugger thanks very much. Of the three types of stripe connect accounts (Standard, Express, Custom), yourself and taintedzodiac provide great tips for (just my luck) Standard and Custom, and I'm using.. Express. I'll read the docs all the same, and report back

Answer (score 1):

This took 2 hours' over customer support to figure out. Would love to know to know how to do this with code (will update if I figure that out). Here's how to do it via the UI:

Start by creating an account (this part uses code):

```rb
require 'stripe'

# use this if stripe test key is in credentials.yml....
# Stripe.api_key = Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:stripe][:test_api_key]

# ....otherwise simply use this:
Stripe.api_key = 'sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc'

account = Stripe::Account.create({
  type: 'express',
  country: 'US',
  requested_capabilities: ['card_payments', 'transfers']
})
```

Since Stripe docs don't contain a full set of connected user info, don't enter random values, as there's a very high chance it won't approve something you enter (e.g. an invalid address, phone number, social security number etc etc). Use these instead:

- Email: use something really random or else a real person will get a stripe test email `sdlfkjsdlkfjslkdfj@sldkfjkkhfksdjdfkj.com`
- Business type: Individual
- Phone: (US) 0000000000
- Legal name: Use anything here
- DOB: Anything
- Address - this is fussy. Here's one that works:
- Address line 1: 777 Brockton Avenue
- Address line 2: Leave this field empty
- City: Abington
- State: Massachusetts
- ZIP: 02351
- Last four digits of social security: 0000

Now the connected account can receive a payment intent like so

```rb
    payment_intent = Stripe::PaymentIntent.create({
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
      amount: @amount_minor_unit, # e.g. 1000 for $10
      currency: @currency, # e.g. "USD"
      application_fee_amount: 123, 
      transfer_data: {
        destination: @user.stripe_account,
      },
    })
```